# Asp.net C# diplay textboxes or checkboxes in a listview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 tables in my database where one table is called "Generic Questions" and the other "Job Questions" both have a column name "Questiontext" So, the idea is they both makeup a job application.

Right now, i only have 3 questions per "Questiontext" but will be adding more later.

I have a data layer where i am accessing this database. The idea is to make something like an application. So, i would like to bind those data sets to labels because they are a series of questions. Then, i could have text boxes next to them or checkboxes.

Is there a way to add textboxes to some questions and add maybe a checkbox to another?

```
       JobPositionSystemDAL jps = new JobPositionSystemDAL();
        DataSet ds = jps.OpenJobOpeningByID(1);
        DataSet ds2 = jps.GetGenericQuestions();
        ListView1.DataSource = ds;
        ListView1.DataBind();


        ListView2.DataSource = ds2;
        ListView2.DataBind();
```

here is the code for the listview. which works good.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" 
                style="margin-right: 42px; margin-top: 28px; margin-left: 35px;">
            <LayoutTemplate>
 <table>
 <thead>
 <tr>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </LayoutTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
 <tr>
 <td><%# Eval("QUESTIONTEXT")%></td>
 </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
 </table>
 <div>

 <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server">
 <LayoutTemplate>
 <table>
 <thead>
 <tr>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
  <td><%# Eval("QUESTIONTEXT")%></td>
  </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Repeator or ListView can do the job. Rather than showing this code show the markup for either of those controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There must be a column in your query which would contain the questions (Using a Select * from database table is a bad idea, please specify table columns name in your queries)
2. Just place a boundfield/template field inside a gridview & databind as you are doing right now
   if using template field use it like this

   ```
   <asp:label ID="yourLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind YourQuestionColumnName%>' ></asp:TextBox>
   ```
3. You can then place a checkbox list/radio button list inside a template field & bind that with your answers dataset.